# Upgrading to php 7.0 is not applying shopping cart price rules in magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I am using flat rate shipping of type per item on products and applying shopping cart price rule for free shipping if order value (subtotal) is greater than 1000. This is working fine if i am using php 5.5.9.

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 but it installed with php 7.0.8 and now this shopping cart price rule is not being applied as shown in screenshots below.

Php versions then 
[image: php-5.5.9]
and now
[image: php-7.0.8]

Shopping cart price rule settings
[image]
[image]

Flat rate shipping setting

[image]

**Frontend earlier with php 5.5.9**

Below 1000
shipping charge is display and added to grand total
[image]

above 1000
shipping charge is not displayed and grand total is same as subtotal
[image]

**Frontend now with php 7.0.8**

[image: Promotion not applied even though condition met]

Initially whole magento itself wasn't loading after php upgrade but looking at this [link](https://www.atwix.com/magento/magento-and-php-7/) i made the necessary change and resolved that conflict but now i cannot seem to find a solution to this. Can somebody please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install inchoo's php7 patch. Works like a charm. Additionally test and verify that your modules and theme are php7 compatible as well. Use the php7 compatibility checker for that.

https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7
https://github.com/sstalle/php7cc

Comment: Will check into the suggestion and update. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks for the pointer. this helped me to check into other areas also which otherwise i would not have checked.